# jsp dont load css and scripts after deploy

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp

I am trying to deploy a java jsp application, but the view not charge .css and .js files, as I can fix this?
 the file structure is as follows:

```
-Project
   -META-INF
   -WEB_INF
   -resources
     -CSS
     -scripts
   -administracion
   -control
   -inicio
```

Comment: You have to provide the code you use to load the assets.

Comment: can you share your code so that it will be easy to answer?

Comment: Did you call those css and js location in your js file?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/your_js_file.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

scripts and css are folders outside`WEB-INF` and contains  `.js` files and `.css` files respectively

Answer (score 0):

Your could add lines given below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/your_js_file.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/CSS/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

logically he called .css and .js files from the JSP.
when I'm editing the project work perfectly, but do not load the deployment

```
    <link href="../resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../resources/css/colors.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../resources/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../resources/scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```